# Language redirect laravel

Tags: php, laravel, lang

I have a categories with slug. 
Example: `site.com/category/auto` - this is english slug
`site.com/category/mashini` - but this is russian slug

When I switch language on this pages, they are not translited. How I can redirect on slug with certain language?

My middleware Language.php:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Session::has('applocale') AND array_key_exists(Session::get('applocale'), Config::get('langs'))) {
        App::setLocale(Session::get('applocale'));
    }
    else { // This is optional as Laravel will automatically set the fallback language if there is none specified
        App::setLocale(Config::get('app.fallback_locale'));
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::group( [ 'prefix' => App::getLocale(), 'middleware' =>\App\Http\Middleware\Language::class ], function (\Illuminate\Routing\Router $router) {

Route::get('country/{countries}', 'Countries\CountryController@show')->name('country');
Route::get('countries', 'Countries\CountryController@index')->name('countryindex');

Route::get('category/{categories}', 'Categories\CategoryController@show')->name('cate');

});
```

CategoryController:

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Models\CategoriesTranslations  $categories
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(CategoriesTranslations $categories)
{
    return view('categories/categoryShow', compact('categories'));
}
}
```

Comment: You could check on the category controller if the current category slug language matches the session lang, if not, redirect to the proper category.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: have you solved your question?

Comment: that because middleware happen after routing call , So you are asking to get the local value before you set the value in the middleware